# How do you change the icon of the `wwwroot` folder in a .NET Core project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, when I want to create an ASP.NET Core Web Application from scratch using either one of these standard .NET Core project templates:

- **Console App (.NET Core)**
- **Class Library (.NET Core)**

These project templates; obviously would not include the `wwwroot` folder. So, when I add the folder to my project it will look like (and behave like) a standard folder:

[image: .NET Core Console App]

When you create it using the  **ASP.NET Core Web Application** project template, the `wwwroot` folder looks like this:

[image: ASP.NET Core Web Application]

**Question - Appearance (Icon)**

> How do you change the icon of the `wwwroot` folder to look like the one found in the **ASP.NET Core Web Application** project template?

---

**Additional Question - Behavior (Copying Files to Output Directory)**
In the standard .NET Core project, I would have to add this to my `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="wwwroot\**" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

so that it copies all my files from the `wwwroot` folder to the output directory similar to the ASP.NET Core Web Application project. I looked in the ASP.NET Core Web Application's `.csproj` file and didn't see anything like that.

I'm assuming the answer to the main question will also provide the answer for this one, as the project templates are obviously different. **I can't seem to find the resources online to help me manually edit this myself.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very likely that it is a feature of VS to show special icon when the project type is a web project. Not every wish can be fulfilled.

Comment: @LexLi - I would find it odd that you can't manually convert the project template to a different one by editing the project configuration somewhere.

Comment: VS is not an open source editor with all possibilities. So far there is no obvious documentation on the icon part.

Comment: @LexLi Based on this documentation, i think it is possible that `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` is the difference. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/03/07/announcing-visual-studio-2017/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After reading [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/03/07/announcing-visual-studio-2017/) that announced the new tooling in Visual Studio 2017, I found out that it was in fact possible.

> I noticed that the ASP.NET Core Web Application project uses a different value under the `Project` node in the `.csproj` file.
>
> ```
> <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
> ```

Whereas the standard project templates used `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> ← ← ← ← //change this to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**Once I changed the value to** `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` and saved the `csproj` file, the project upgraded itself, and the `wwwroot` folder was added to my project automatically *(but excluded)*, like this:

[image: Step1]

Then I included it into the project and now:

[image: Step2]

Great! I hope this answer helps others.

Comment: This did indeed work for me, but my Sdk setting was already "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web". I removed ".Web", saved the file, then added it back and saved the file again. The icon was restored and the folder was moved to its proper place (just after the Properties folder, whereas it had previously been positioned alphabetically). Also, I didn't have to include the folder manually -- it didn't get excluded during the process.

Comment: I removed wwwroot by accident.  I recreated it, and it did not have the icon.  I just then closed vs.net and re-opened and everything was good again. :)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure this line is included in the ItemGroup below

```
 <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
```

Comment: It automagically added this node to my csproj: 
`<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same **problem**
but Its better not to call this a problem bec there is no difrence between the wwwroot folder with the icon and the one with no icon
you have to firstly find the file yourproject.csproj file
its filled by some tags
on the top of this file you will see the  tag
it is valued like this  Sdk=Microsoft.NET.Sdk
try to revalue it like this **Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.web**
then try to remove the unusual wwwroot folder
and regenerate the folder and name it wwwroot
this time it will have the icon that you prefer